# Need to resize multiple image files

Tags: images, batch-processing, image-editing, free, open-source

Looking for recommendations for a free or open-source application that can batch resize multiple image files (.jpg)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to help people give you the best answers possible.

Comment: This is just too broad, a google search would probably give you enough results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify: 1) What’s your OS? 2) What are your constraints? For example, do you want something with a GUI or a command-line tool? 3) Do you have any further requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I thought this had been asked but didnt find it from my searches. You didn't specify an OS or specify if you were increasing or decreasing the file size. So here is a dump of some tools or apps I've used throughout the years.

A great utility to use is Imagemagick. It has [convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) and [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify). Example with `convert`:

```
for image in *.jpg; do
    convert "$image" -resize 80% "${image/.jpg/-80%.jpg}"
done
```

If you're on a Mac and you dont want to script in the terminal you could use the built in Mac Preview:

- Select all the images you want resized in the Finder, and then open them within the Preview app
- From Preview, select all of the images that you want to batch resize from the left-side thumbnail drawer (Command+A will select them all)
- Now, go to the menu labeled “Tools”, and then choose “Adjust Size”
- Enter a value for what you want the new width and height to be
- Next, navigate to the ‘File’ menu and click “Save All” or, to save a NEW version that is resized, choose “Export Selected Images…” or “Save As”

Reference: [Batch Resize Images on Mac with Preview](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/16/batch-resize-images-on-mac-with-preview/). If you're looking for a paid app for Mac there is [Image Resizer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/image-resizer-resize-photos/id1188274404?mt=12).

If you own or have Photoshop this can be achieved as an action:

- Create a new custom Action
- Go to File → Open an image
- Hit the Action record/play button.
- Crop to required size.
- File → Export → Export As → JPG.
- Hit OK.
- Close image.
- Hit Stop button on Actions panel.

reference: [I need to batch resize 20 images.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2441162)